# Are Questions about finding similar sounding music On Topic

Tags: discussion, topics

I am new to this SE so I wanted to ask if questions about similar sounding songs and genre are on topic. Example below is not meant to be answered in the meta but is just an example of the kind of question I mean.

```
I have been listening to some old Disney songs and I have not been able to find many songs
similar to Hellfire from the Hunchback of Notre Dame. Could anyone lead me to similar
artists/songs and tell me what genre or combinations of genres would this song fall under?

The main points I want to find is the powerful voice, the tempo of the singing, how he 
pauses every few words in sections of the song.
```

Comment: Read http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry Aaron - definitely not on topic here.